# From SQL Server Management Studio to Python using polars

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, python-polars

I would like to connect SQL Server Management Studio with Python using polars and connectorx function:

I wrote this chunk of code

```
import connectorx as cx 
import urllib.parse

conn = 'mssql://sa:{}@{}:5432/Planning_insight?encrypt=true&trusted_connection=true'.format(
    urllib.parse.quote_plus('MYPASSWORD'),
    urllib.parse.quote_plus('MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS')
    )                                                                        
str_query = f"SELECT * FROM raw.calendar"

cx.read_sql(conn,str_query)
```

but after 30 second, it returned this error

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 10
4 conn = 'mssql://sa:{}@{}:5432/Planning_insight?encrypt=true&trusted_connection=true'.format(
5     urllib.parse.quote_plus('MYPASSWORD'),
6     urllib.parse.quote_plus('MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS')
7     )
8 str_query = f"SELECT * FROM raw.calendar"
---> 10 cx.read_sql(conn,str_query)

File c:\Users\lorenzsc\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\padp2\lib\site-packages\connectorx_*init*_.py:224, in read_sql(conn, query, return_type, protocol, partition_on, partition_range, partition_num, index_col)
221 except ModuleNotFoundError:
222     raise ValueError("You need to install pandas first")
--> 224 result = _read_sql(
225     conn,
226     "pandas",
227     queries=queries,
228     protocol=protocol,
229     partition_query=partition_query,
230 )
231 df = reconstruct_pandas(result)
233 if index_col is not None:

RuntimeError: Timed out in bb8

Can anyone help me?

This part might be weird:

```
urllib.parse.quote_plus('MYPASSWORD')
```

I have used this function since my password and other parts of the connection string contain special characters.

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. You don't connect to it, you use it to query databases.

Comment: The error itself says `You need to install pandas first`. It looks like the query was executed, the data returned but when the time came to create a DataFrame, Pandas was missing.

Comment: Have you checked the [Database page](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/io/database/#read-from-a-database) in the Polars docs? You should use `pl.read_database`. Polars uses connectorx by default

Comment: There seem to be a number of problems in the connection code presented, e.g.: 1) `connectorx` is the connection library for MySQL/MariaDB databases; 2) you specify port 5432, the default port for PostgreSQL, in addition to using a named instance `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS`; and 3) you specify a username and password, for SQL Logon authentication, but also specify `trusted_connection=true` to use Active Directory/Windows Logon authentication. What are you actually trying to connect to? And how?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos sorry for the lack of clarity, even if pandas is installed the code return the same error. The function pl.read_database is analogous to cx.read_sql so will return the same error.

Comment: AlwaysLearning so you think that my main problem is that connectorx does not permit the connession with SSMS? About point 2) and 3) when the function started to return the runtime error I began to try everything hahaa so i changed the port name to 1433 to 5432 and I added truested connection = true. The authentication that I use is SQL Logon authentication and I work with SSMS. Thank you for your answer